# Oracle 10g (32 bit) on Windows 7 x64

Tags: database, oracle, oracle10g, database-administration

Anybody here does have an succesful experience in installing Oracle 10g Release 2 (10.2) for Microsoft Windows (32-Bit) on 64 bit Windows 7? No matter which installation type i select on the first screen i get this: [image: Error screen] Is it possible to install such a configuration? My java version is 1.5.0_19 (also i have 1.4.2 and 1.6_26 but final product require 1.5). Database Hardware requirements are satisfied (4GB RAM and 65GB on the disk).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've managed to install Oracle 64 bit for Windows Vista on Windows 7 as described [here](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=4493082), using `-ignoreSysPrereqs` option for the installation executable.

Comment: @semenbari, yes.

Answer (score 2):

Installing a 32bit Oracle version on a 64bit Windows is not supported (See Metalink Document 1060806.1).

You will need to install the 64bit version.